# Processing using Matlab

Tags: signal-analysis, dft, continuous-signals

I'm new to Matlab.As a beginner, I want to work on few signals which are used in day today life and extract useful information through it. Can someone please help me from where I could start or share a blog which might help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad. Since you probably have Matlab (I hope), Matlab help is where to start, for instance [Measurements and Feature Extraction](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/measurements-and-feature-extraction.html). From there, you can start with signals available in Matlab, get some tutorial code, etc.